# Are there printable, non-whitespace Unicode characters supported by any modern browser and platform?

Tags: unicode, cross-platform, unicode-string

For a random password generator, I'd like to optionally generate random passwords that contain non-whitespace, non-control letter and letterlike unicode characters. The user would copy and paste generated passwords in the system's default unicode encoding (e.g. UTF-8) into browser windows and text entry widgets on the browser/platform.

However, I don't know which characters are supported across operating systems Windows, Linux, macOS, Android and iOS in common user configurations in common recent browsers. Is there some minimal list of unicode symbols that is supported on all platforms with unicode support?

Or does this depend entirely on the user's configuration, i.e. which system font is used? Should I rather stick with ascii and latin1 generators, which I have already implemented?

Comment: I would limit the password to just the printable ASCII characters: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, punctuation, etc.

Comment: I already have that. Why would you not give the user an optional choice of additional Unicode characters?

Comment: Your issue boils down to capabilities of specific fonts, not Unicode itself.  You could certainly generate a password using whatever Unicode characters you want, but different fonts support rendering different ranges of Unicode characters, there is no single font that supports the entire Unicode repertoire. So you would need to restrict your password to only the Unicode characters that are supported by a single font that every platform supports.  And frankly, there aren't that many fonts that *every* platform supports equally.  But most fonts support the ASCII characters, at least...

Comment: If you really want to support non-ASCII characters in your password, I would suggest allowing the user to select a desired font first, and then you can enumerate that font's supported Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be sure a browser can display a international run of text is to use [web fonts](http://caniuse.com/ttf). For an app it's a bit simpler as you can bundle the font with the app and install it at the same time.

In both cases you need to check the licensing of the chosen font allows the kind of distribution you envision. So not really suitable for a general-purpose password generator.

Be aware that many unicode combinations won't be type-able except with very specific keyboard layouts /input methods. So you'll be forcing the user to copy and paste passwords he can not type.

Lastly, an unicode encoding point won't necessarily correspond to a single symbol. Many encoding points are combining symbols that can only be used with specific other symbols in specific orders.

You should really start by adding "simple" unicode blocks such as basic greek or cyrillic letters, the dingbat block, arrows and engineering symbols, avoid anything combining, avoid ligatures, diacritics, complex asian scripts etc.

Greek and cyrillic in particular should be supported by most modern systems without addons. They require so few symbols compared to most asian scripts only the most rabid barebone system will skip them.

Dingbat and arrows/engineering symbols will require specific fonts to be sure of support but those are easy to find (for exemple, in [symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/)) and this kind of symbol won't require a text engine capable of complex text. Avoid math symbols or carefully screen them, quite a lot of them combine [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm) will tell you which symbol is available in common fonts. That requires knowing which font ship with which OS, and to be aware of font versions (a later version of the same font may include more glyphs, but few systems update the fonts they shipped with).

That should be sufficient to strengthen your generator without hitting strange corner cases.